# Not able to install Firebase

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I am new to use "Firebase" and I am getting issue while installing "Firebase" in my ionic app.

node and npm version:-

[image]

error getting while installing:-

[image]

please suggest me how to install it or provide any article. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go through the official documention and follow the steps. It is fairly easy. 
[Firebase installation documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/)